# Can't access localhost through Squid proxy

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, squid

I've set up a proxy server using `squid` on my local machine running on port 3128. My apache server is up and now I'm trying to access my localhosts sites through squid proxy but the request keeps loading with no response until it stops. On Firefox, I set FoxyProxy (127.0.0.1:3128) and try to access 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't respond. At `/etc/squid/squid.conf` I got:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 
#http_access deny !Safe_ports #intentionally commented this line
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports #intentionally commented this line
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_port 3128
```

I also noticed that squid's `access.log` is 0 bytes, this means that (I guess) the request didn't even reached squid.  What could I be missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, localhost and 127.0.0.1 are in the exception list (No proxy for... in Options, Advanced, Network, Settings)
Try to remove them!